# condição hyperlink click

Tags: php

Quero que quando clica-se no hyperlink pela segunda vez executa-se outro codigo.

```
<a href=?ordem=nom>$lib_nom</a>


//ordena dados do array ASC
array_multisort( $affiche_ord, SORT_ASC, $affiche_tab );

//ordena dados do array DESC
array_multisort( $affiche_ord, SORT_DESC, $affiche_tab );
```

Se click uma vez fazer o ASC se for a segunda vez DESC, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? Como está não faz muito sentido... Quer fazer isso do lado do cliente ou servidor? Explique um pouco do contexto pf.

Comment: Tenho um link. Quando clico a primeira vez, quero que execute este codigo array_multisort( $affiche_ord, SORT_ASC, $affiche_tab ); e quando voltar a clicar executar array_multisort( $affiche_ord, SORT_DESC, $affiche_tab );

Comment: Ok, e quer que o click seja no lado do cliente e que corra o `sort` no PHP/servidor... porque não fazer isso no JavaScript? Quer recarregar a página ou fazer isso via AJAX?

Comment: é um link que recarrega a pagina. Sim do lado do cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira, alternando entre um parâmetro e outro, capturando 
a variável `ordem` com `$_GET` e aplicando na função de acordo com o parâmetro enviado pelo link:

```
<?php
$ordem = $_GET['ordem'];
$nova_ordem = empty($ordem) || $ordem == 'SORT_DESC' ? 'SORT_ASC' : 'SORT_DESC';

echo '<a href="?ordem='.$nova_ordem.'">$lib_nom</a>';

array_multisort( $affiche_ord, $ordem, $affiche_tab );
?>
```

Se o parâmetro `ordem` for vazio, será incluído no link o valor `?ordem=SORT_ASC`, e depois vai alternando com `?ordem=SORT_DESC` conforme o link for sendo clicado.